# Heroku PostgreSQL user and database creation

Tags: postgresql, heroku, yaml, ruby-on-rails-4.2, heroku-postgres

Currently I have my Ruby on Rails program running great on my Linux Ubuntu development environment, and now I want to run it live on my website, and get it hosted on Heroku.

The problem is that I don't know how to create a user and a database on Heroku. I have tried the command

```
heroku run rake db:create
```

I got the error:

```
permission denied for database - user does nothave connect privilage
```

I also tried the command

```
heroku run su - postgres
```

and it posted that I need to use the terminal so I do not know how to proceed.

This is my `database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter:  postgresql
  host:     localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: app_development

test:
   <<: *default
   database: app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: app_production
```

How do I set up my database and the proper connections with my Heroku PostgreSQL database?

i also did this

```
heroku pg:info
```

which gave me this

```
shrouded-reaches-3063 has no heroku-postgresql databases.
```

also tried this

```
heroku addons | grep POSTGRES
```

but nothing was printed

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev 
!    `addons:create` is not a heroku command.
!    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

also this

```
heroku pg:wait
```

and displayed nothing... this really is something T_T really need some major help here , and will be really greatful for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you provisioned a database?  What does `heroku addons` say?   You can create an add-on as documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-the-add-on) with `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`

Comment: I strongly suggest removing your password from your comment. Further, the full command you want is `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev` - see the article here for full info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-the-add-on

Comment: heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
 !    `addons:create` is not a heroku command.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.

Comment: that is what it returns i have been trying to get this to work all afternoon but to no avail T_T

Comment: in the start i specified that it will use the PG, and its working great locally, but with heroku its now working , it wont even let me create the database T_T

Comment: Looks like the docs are outdated: try `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev` - note the use of add vs. create. You can also add a DB via the web dashboard, and use tab completion to see available commands when using the Heroku Toolbelt.

Comment: hey , apparently your code here   heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev   works, it worked with the basic one that i did with the sample, i tried it and it did the job for that testing app...sadly it didnt work with the main app that i was hoping to fix, i called in customer support and they said it was some SMTP and the host is busy...not got a headache trying to get this thing to run , sad to say my worst day , errors with SMTP , and working with PG based one with no SQLite.,,also i think this one is the problem ,gem "mailboxer", github: "div/mailboxer", branch: "rails42-foreigner"

Comment: The docs are correct.  `addons:create` is the right thing.  If `addons:create` isn't working then I suspect you don't have the latest version of the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/), or you have some weird local conflict due to a heroku gem or something.

Answer (score 1):

**!!!NOT IN THE DOCUMENTATION!!!**

```
 heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --version=12 --app "APPNAME" --name "APPNAME-database"
```

**--app** : Specify the heroku app you want to add the database too. Really good if you have more than one heroku app.

**--name** : The name you would like to give your database. I like to take my application name and postfix it with "database" as a nice convention. Better than whatever randomly generated name you'll get.

**APPNAME**: A placeholder for whatever your application name is.

No mention of any of this on heroku.com documentation pages for addons in general or postgres addon. I think I came to this via guessing based on documentation for creating apps. But I don't remember. This was in my notes from 5+ years ago. However, I just tried it, **still works as of 2022.05.14**.